# How to make a specific row in one column editable in datagridview when cellcontentclick in edit column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I try it has not succeeded if I uncomment for the code `DataGridView2.Columns("Qty").ReadOnly = True`
then it can be editable but all rows in one column but I want to be editable in the row I select after I click edit and if I move another row then it is readonly
Please Guide me

Thanks

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 DataGridView2.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster()
        DataGridView2.Columns("No").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView2.Columns("Invnop").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView2.Columns("CodeProduct").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView2.Columns("Qty").ReadOnly = True
    End Sub
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
 If e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
                If DataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
                    Return
                End If
            DataGridView2.Columns("Qty").ReadOnly = False

        End If
    End Sub
```

view datagridview

[image: view datagridview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGridViewCell` inherits the [`ReadOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.readonly?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property from its owning [column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.readonly?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks) or [row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.readonly?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks). Setting the property to `True` means you can't use the cell's `EditingControl` to change the value and it's only can be changed by code.

You can instead set the [`DataGridView.EditMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.EditMode)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) property to `DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically` to disable putting the cells in edit mode by the mouse and key inputs. By code in the `CellContentClick` event handler, select and put a given cell in edit mode when you click the link cell of the selected row.

Example to put the `Qty` cell in edit mode.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView2.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster()
    DataGridView2.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
        DataGridView2.CurrentCell = DataGridView2(3, e.RowIndex)
        DataGridView2.BeginEdit(True)
    End If
End Sub
```

You can use the columns `Name` property to identify them instead of the index..

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellContentClick
    If DataGridView2.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView2.Columns("coledit") Then
        DataGridView2.CurrentCell = DataGridView2("Qty", e.RowIndex)
        DataGridView2.BeginEdit(True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Another example on how you should populate the grid and add the `DataGridViewLinkColumn`.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect
    DataGridView2.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
    DataGridView2.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster().ToList()
    DataGridView2.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewLinkColumn With {
        .Name = "coledit",
        .Text = "Edit",
        .HeaderText = "",
        .UseColumnTextForLinkValue = True,
        .TrackVisitedState = False
    })
    ' Optional...
    DataGridView2.Columns("coledit").DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Grid.Columns("coledit").DefaultCellStyle.BackColor
End Sub
```

Side note, IMO the `FullRowSelect` is not appropriate `SelectionMode` here. Use the default `RowHeaderSelect` value instead.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I've tried from your code and from your step2 but it hasn't worked in me. Could there be something wrong in me

Comment: @pret Don't set the `ReadOnly` properties to `True`. It must set to `False`.

Comment: okay I set from bound column properties and for `Coledit` I set readyonly to false too

Comment: I've tried it anyway I can't edit if there is something wrong in my DataGridView

Comment: @pret What happens when you use this code? And, how do you add the link column? After setting the grid's `DataSource` property? What does this  `GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster()` return? Change it to `DataGridView2.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster().ToList()`, double check your code, and try. On other hand, if you want to make the entire selected row editable, then this is another story. So, what exactly do you need here? What do you want to happen when you click the link?

Comment: I encountered a problem , if i make it like this works editable  `If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(4, e.RowIndex) DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True) End If`  but Why is my Edit Link column to 0 but the DataGridView position to Column 4

Comment: I add directly to the datagridview with the header name and for datapropertyname it must be the same as the model class but for column link i did not fill in datapropertyname and headername also I made blank and only the deisgn name became "coledit"

Comment: `You can use the columns Name property to identify them instead of the index..`  Your solution works perfectly and  for this `Another example on how you should populate the grid and add the DataGridViewLinkColumn.` This solution from you goes perfectly if I run the first answer from you. Why if adding directly in the DataGridView without going through the code changes the position of the index column?

Comment: @pret You didn't post that part of code (adding the link column) to tell you why. Did you play with the columns `DisplayIndex` property? Did you add the link column first? It depends.

Comment: `You didn't post that part of code (adding the link column) to tell you why` For this I added directly from the DataGridView column without going through the code . ` Did you play with the columns DisplayIndex property?` No , `Did you add the link column first? It depends` The position of the link column is in the last position of the DataGridView

Comment: @pret Check the link column position in the grids `Columns` collection and its `DisplayIndex` property. You need to visit the grid's documentation and use it a lot to master it. It's a complex nested control.

Comment: I have another post maybe you can give me a guide . [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76954293/how-to-create-a-user-role-based-permissions-for-each-form-in-dapper-with-access?noredirect=1#comment135673930_76954293)

Comment: Why did you remove your answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76975666/why-looping-each-row-in-a-datagridview-doesnt-show-all-value-in-the-messagebox?noredirect=1#comment135709399_76975666) , sorry if I offended you. Because I want to mark your answer