# Why Looping each row in a datagridview doesn't show all value in the messagebox in the vb.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach, datagridview, messagebox

It should also appear in the messagebox for codeproduct "B" if there is something wrong with my code please guide me

I updated the code full making it easier to solve the solution . maybe there is an incorrect method in the code I created
Thanks

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksMaster()
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView2.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster()
 End Sub
```

```
 Private Sub BtnUpdateAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdateAll.Click
        Try
  If DataGridView2.RowCount = 0 Then
                Throw New Exception("no data")
            End If
            For Each item As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                Dim detail = New Stocksoutdetail With {
                            .Qty = CInt(item.Cells("Qty").Value),
                            .Invno = CStr(item.Cells("Invnop").Value),
                             .No = CInt(item.Cells("No").Value),
                             .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells("CodeProduct").Value)
                }
                Dim GetStocks = New Stocks With {
                           .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells("CodeProduct").Value)
                           }
                Dim GetStock = itrservice.GetStock(GetStocks)
                Dim Getprevdetailqtys = New Stocksoutdetail With {
                            .Invno = CStr(item.Cells("Invnop").Value),
                             .No = CInt(item.Cells("No").Value),
                           .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells("CodeProduct").Value)
                           }
                Dim Getprevdetailqty = itrservice.Getprevdetailqty(Getprevdetailqtys)
                Dim ResutlQty_Stock = GetStock.Qty_Stock - (detail.Qty - Getprevdetailqty.Qty)
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                    If ResutlQty_Stock < 0 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("no available stock for Codeproduct " & CStr(row.Cells("CodeProduct").FormattedValue))
                        DataGridView2.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster()
                      Return
                    End If
                Next row

 Dim stocks = New Stocks With {
                        .Qty_Stock = GetStock.Qty_Stock - (detail.Qty - Getprevdetailqty.Qty),
                        .Qty_Stockout = GetStock.Qty_Stockout + (detail.Qty - Getprevdetailqty.Qty),
                        .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells("CodeProduct").Value)
                        }
                itrservice.Updatestock(stocks)
                itrservice.UpdateStocksoutdetail(detail)
            Next item
 MessageBox.Show("successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

```
Public Class Stocksoutdetail
    Public Property No() As Integer
    Public Property Invno() As String
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Qty() As Integer
End Class
Public Class Stocks
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Qty_Stock() As Integer
    Public Property Qty_Stockout() As Integer

End Class
```

'update code method StocksoutdetailService

```
    Public Sub Updatestock(ByVal Obj As Stocks)
        Dim sql = $"UPDATE `Stocks` Set `QTY_STOCK`= {Obj.Qty_Stock},`QTY_STOCKOUT`= {Obj.Qty_Stockout} WHERE `CodeProduct`='{Obj.CodeProduct}';"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql)
        End Using
    End Sub
Public Sub UpdateStocksoutdetail(ByVal Obj As Stocksoutdetail)
        Dim sql = $"UPDATE `Stocksoutdetail` Set `Qty`={Obj.Qty} WHERE `Invno`='{Obj.Invno}' and `No`={Obj.No} and `CodeProduct`='{Obj.CodeProduct}';"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql)
        End Using
    End Sub
```

RESULT FROM IN DATAGRIDVIEW

[image: RESULT FROM IN DATAGRIDVIEW]

Captureeditqtyintransaction

[image: Captureeditqtyintransaction]

Captureafterupdateall

[image: Captureafterupdateall]

Comment: you need to calculate in your for loop as you need the values of the cells

Comment: I can't see `Getprevdetailqty = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells("Qty").Value)` in your code. Where is it? Perhaps you mean: `Getprevdetailqty.Qty = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells("Qty").Value)` ?

Comment: @dr.null , actually the code is the answer from @nbk `Getprevdetailqty = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells("Qty").Value)` or `Getprevdetailqty.Qty = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells("Qty").Value)` so in the original code from me it doesn't exist

Comment: @dr.null , so I want a codeproduct display in messagebox that is not available in stock or less stock but my code only appears one like the example I posted should appear codeproduct 'A" & "B"

Comment: I see, then you gonna need to ask him about it.  Just tried to give a hand.

Comment: **Hint:** You should handle the cell validation events here to _cancel_ the edit if the Qty is greater than the stock and show a message about it. Read [How to: Validate Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-validate-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and try to apply that.

Comment: If you only need to analyze selected rows in a DataGridView, use `DataGridView.SelectedRows`. If you want to analyze the entire data set bound to a DGV, you're better off calculating against the underlying data source instead of looping through the DGV. It tends to lead to easier-to-read and easier-to-maintain code.

Comment: @dr.null , Thank you for your reply, sorry I replied late, `How to: Validate Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control` for this do keep looping in datagridview please guide me

Comment: @HardCode , Thank you for your reply, sorry I replied late, for this `use DataGridView.SelectedRows. If you want to analyze the entire data set bound to a DGV, you're better off calculating against the underlying data source instead of looping through the DGV.` Meaning that you mean when changing the quantity on the row that I selected, it will do an analysis and a message appears that the stock is not available. Please Guide me

Comment: Please add the code in its caller method and confirm whether you need to prevent entering out-of-stock `Qty` values. Also, you have in the first grid `Qty_Stock` and `Qty_Stockout`. Which one is the stock-in-hand? One of them? `Second - First`? Else? and, add the two models of the two grids.

Comment: @dr.null , `Please add the code in its caller method and confirm whether you need to prevent entering out-of-stock Qty values.`  `Dim ResutlQty_Stock = GetStock.Qty_Stock - (detail.Qty - Getprevdetailqty.Qty)` `this is method code ` `you have in the first grid Qty_Stock and Qty_Stockout` `Qty_Stock` is stock-in-hand. I tried to add full code in the error post can I share via textdocument via Google Drive?

Comment: @dr.null , I've managed to update my code in the post maybe this could help for guidance from you

Comment: When producing your no stock available message, you are iterating again through the whole of DataGridView2 (for nested within for). This means that if any product has no stock (Qty_Stock < 0), you will get a message saying that all products are out of stock.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock , You mean I looped again after the message box

Comment: No you loop again before the message box. This means that you report no stock for the first record in the grid, regardless of whether it is the product that has no stock. Product A just happens to be the first product, so you get the message for A and then you Return. I do not understand why you have the nested for loop at all. You should just report for the current record in your main loop: `detail.CodeProduct`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is caused by an unnecessary loop within your first loop.

After calculating ResutlQty_Stock for one row, within the same iteration you start the second loop that takes the value of ResutlQty_Stock for one row and uses the same value to determine whether all of the rows have a value less than zero. (A second problem: You probably meant = 0 instead of < 0 unless you have negative inventory).

Assuming the rest of your code works, change this:

```
Dim ResutlQty_Stock = GetStock.Qty_Stock - (detail.Qty - Getprevdetailqty.Qty)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
        If ResutlQty_Stock < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("no available stock for Codeproduct " & CStr(row.Cells("CodeProduct").FormattedValue))
            DataGridView2.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster()
            Return
        End If
     Next row
```

To this, eliminating the second for loop (as suggested by @JonathanWillcock), changing row.cells to item.cells since item refers to the current DataGridViewRow in your loop, and changing < 0 to = 0.

```
Dim ResutlQty_Stock = GetStock.Qty_Stock - (detail.Qty - Getprevdetailqty.Qty)
If ResutlQty_Stock = 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("no available stock for Codeproduct " & CStr(item.Cells("CodeProduct").FormattedValue))
    DataGridView2.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster()
    Return
End If
```